# Single ended edge in jGraph

Tags: java, jgraphx

I am trying to draw directed graphs using jGraph and Java, however I would like a single ended arrow to notate the starting node.

The only thing I can think of that may be able to do this is to have a Node that has no use, but can be linked to the starting node, and then turn this invisible using

```
graph.getModel().setVisible(Node, false)
```

However, this also removes the edge connecting the 2 nodes.

Is there a way to draw edges that only connect to one node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you were on the right track.

One way to do this is to set the opacity of the starting Node to 0 as in this example:

```
public static mxGraph makeHelloWorldGraph() {
    mxGraph graph = new mxGraph();
    Object parent = graph.getDefaultParent();

    graph.getModel().beginUpdate();
    try {
        Object v1 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, "", 20, 20, 80,
                30,"opacity=0");
        Object v2 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, "World!", 240, 150,
                80, 30);
        graph.insertEdge(parent, null, "Edge", v1, v2);
    } finally {
        graph.getModel().endUpdate();
    }
    return graph;
}
```

Hope that helps, I've been struggling with this library myself.

Comment: This is excellent thanks, is there a list somewhere of all these labels? such as shape and colour?

Comment: @Matt the only place I've been able to find a reference is in the api documentation for mxConstants. The style keys are all of the form STYLE_[KEYNAME] as in STYLE_OPACITY. So shape would be STYLE_SHAPE and color is STYLE_FILLCOLOR which translates to the strings "shape" and "fillColor" respectively. It's kind of an obtuse way to figure it out, but it works.